# How to factor $^{49}−$ over $GF(7)$ as a product of irreducible polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

**Question:** How to factor $^{49}−$ over $GF(7)$ as a product of irreducible polynomials?

**My approach:** would like to know if it's okay, any help is appreciated.

$$\begin{align}P(x) &= x^{49} - x\\
 &= x(x^{48} -1)\\
 &= x(x^{24} +1)(x^{24} -1) \\
&= x(x^{12} - 1)(x^{24} +1)(x^{12}+1) \\
&= x(x^6-1)(x^6+1)(x^{24}+1)(x^{12}+1)\\
&=x(x^3-1)(x^3+1)(x^6+1)(x^{24}+1)(x^{12}+1)\\
&=x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1-x)(x^2+1+x)(x^2+1)(x^4+1-x^2)(x^8+1)(x^{16}+1-x^8)(x^4+1)(x^8+1-x^4)\\
&=x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)(x^8+1)(x^2+1-x)(x^2+1+x)(x^4+1-x^2)(x^8+1-x^4)(x^{16}+1-x^8)\end{align}$$

**For your convenience:** (image below)
[image]

**Another approach:**

$GF(49)$ has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb F_7$. Over $GF(49)$ the polynomial $x^{49}-x$ has $7$ linear factors $x-t,t=0,...,6,$ and $21$ quadratic factors, one of which is $x^2+6x+6.$

Hence, working modulo $7$, if we set $x^2=x+1$, we can take $x+2$ as a generator (its first few powers are $x+2,5x+5,6x+1,5x+1,2x,6x+2,6x+3,5,...)$ because $(x+2)^t \neq 1$ for $1 \le t \le 47$ and, of course, $(x+2)^{48} = 1$. There are many other choices I guess.

Comment: Note that $x^{49}\equiv x$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb F_7$ so you should at least have every first-order polynomial once.

Comment: I haven't looked too closely at your factoring, but it seems to be generally valid over any field. I suspect that you haven't used that we are working specifically over $GF(7)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You mean $GF(49)$ has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb F_7$. Over $GF(49)$ the polynomial $x^{49}-x$ has $7$ linear factors $x-t,t=0,...,6,$ and $21$ quadratic factors, one of which is $x^2+6x+6.$

Hence, working modulo $7$, if we set $x^2=x+1$, we can take $x+2$ as a generator (its first few powers are $x+2,5x+5,6x+1,5x+1,2x,6x+2,6x+3,5,...)$ because $(x+2)^t \neq 1$ for $1 \le t \le 47$ and, of course, $(x+2)^{48} = 1$. There are many other choices I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $(\pm1)^2=1=-6$, $(\pm2)^2=4=-3$ and $(\pm3)^2=2=-5$ and using the completion of the square "from the outer term", $$x^4+ax^2+b^2=(x^2\pm b)^2+(a\mp2b)x^2,$$ you can further get (blue=incomplete factorization)
\begin{align}
(x^2+1−x)&=(x+3)^2-1=(x+2)(x-3)\\
(x^2+1+x)&=(x-3)^2-1=(x-2)(x+3)\\ 
(x^4+1)&=(x^2+1)^2-2x^2=(x^2+1)^2-(3x)^2=(x^2-3x+1)(x^2+3x+1)\\ 
(x^4+1−x^2)&=(x^2+3)^2-1=(x^2-3)(x^2+2)\\ 
\color{blue}{(x^8+1)}&=\color{blue}{(x^4-3x^2+1)(x^4+3x^2+1)}\\
(x^4-3x^2+1)&=(x^2-1)^2-x^2=(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x-1)\\
(x^4+3x^2+1)&=(x^2-1)^2+5x^2=(x^2-1)^2-(3x)^2=(x^2-3x-1)(x^2+3x-1)\\ 
\color{blue}{(x^8+1−x^4)}&=\color{blue}{(x^4-3)(x^4+2)}\\
(x^4-3)&=(x^2+2)^2-4x^2=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)\\
(x^4+2)&=(x^2-3)^2+6x^2=(x^2-x-3)(x^2+x-3)\\ 
\color{blue}{(x^{16}+1−x^8)}&=\color{blue}{(x^4-2x^2+2)(x^4+2x^2+2)(x^4-x^2-3)(x^4+x^2-3)}\\
(x^4-2x^2+2)&=(x^2+3)^2-x^2=(x^2-x+3)(x^2+x+3)\\
(x^4+2x^2+2)&=(x^2+3)^2-4x^2=(x^2-2x+3)(x^2+2x+3)\\
(x^4-x^2-3)&=(x^2-2)^2-4x^2=(x^2-2x-2)(x^2+2x-2)\\
(x^4+x^2-3)&=(x^2-2)^2-9x^2=(x^2-3x-2)(x^2+3x-2)\\
\end{align}

Comment: apart from that, the solution is okay? :)

Comment: That depends on what "okay" means. Your factorization is correct, just not completely down to irreducible factors.

Comment: I see, adding the blue factorization completes the solution I assume :)

Comment: The other way around, the blue lines have reducible factors on the right side, the factors for the complete factorization are the right sides of the black lines (the following black lines for the blue lines).

Comment: Oh right, thank you so much.